# Can I stack dataframes with different numbers of columns in R?

Tags: r, rbind

Let's say I have

```
x y z
1 2 1
1 4 2
```

and

```
x y
2 5
7 1
```

can I stack them so that the z values are just null for observations from the second dataframe?

Comment: `dplyr::bind_rows(df1, df2)`

Comment: This works, thank you!